# Is it possible to prevent new paragraph node with enter in editor?

Tags: lexical, lexicaljs

I´m trying to create a "one line" message component based on Lexical, but i´m unable to prevent the enter key to create a new paragraph.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

I´ve added styling with

```
white-space: nowrap!important; 
      resize: none;
```

and i´ve tried to MaxLengthPlugin ( which works but if enter in there it creates two lines)

also tried to add

```
<EditorWrapper ref={onRef} data-testid="editor" 
        onKeyDown={event => {
            if (event.key === 'Enter') {
              event.preventDefault();
            } 
          }}>
```

I was expecting this to prevent the new paragraph with enter, but still adds a new paragraph in the editor.

Answer (score 10):

I was able to create a single line editor by using [registerNodeTransform](https://lexical.dev/docs/api/classes/lexical.LexicalEditor#registernodetransform) to remove the `LineBreakNode` as soon as it's created. It doesn't feel like the *best* solution, but it works.

```
editor.registerNodeTransform(LineBreakNode, (node) => {
  node.remove();
});
```

I also explored listening to the `KEY_ENTER_COMMAND` command, but that didn't prevent newlines from being pasted into the editor.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! The `LineBreakNode` helped to stop the users from adding `</br>` but I also had to register to the `RootNode` to prevent new paragraphs.

`mergeRegister(
editor.registerNodeTransform(RootNode, (rootNode: RootNode) => {
    if (rootNode.getChildrenSize() <= 1) return;
    rootNode.getLastChild()?.remove();
}),
editor.registerNodeTransform(LineBreakNode, (node) => {
    node.remove();
}),
)
`

Comment: By the way, the following comment by Dominic Gannaway gives a good explanation of why `editor.registerNodeTransform` is a good approach:

`The simplest way is to use a node transform on your heading node and check its children for a line break and remove it. This will scale well for when someone might copy and paste a linebreak in too (vs the naive approach of blocking the keyboard shortcut).` [Source](https://github.com/facebook/lexical/issues/3675#issuecomment-1371310089)`

Answer (score 4):

You can register the command `INSERT_PARAGRAPH_COMMAND` and then return true. By returning true you tell lexical that you have handled the paragraph insert and the default lexical code will not execute.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
   return editor.registerCommand(
      INSERT_PARAGRAPH_COMMAND, 
      () => {
          return true;
      },
      COMMAND_PRIORITY_EDITOR
);}, [editor]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you only want to edit in one line and not allow multiple lines.

For this you can try to use `INSERT_LINE_BREAK_COMMAND` and prevent line breaks from being added by returning `true` for the command.

```
editor.registerCommand(INSERT_LINE_BREAK_COMMAND, () => true, COMMAND_PRIORITY_LOW)
```

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve this by listening on the contenteditable element and use e.preventDefault() like so:

```
<LexicalComposer
  <PlainTextPlugin
    contentEditable={
      <ContentEditable
        onKeyDown={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
        }}
      />
    }
  />
</LexicalComposer>
```

Comment: In this way no para will be inserted, but even normal characters are blocked as well?

Answer (score 0):

Commands are one way to handle `Enter` Key.

```
    useEffect(() => {
    return editor.registerCommand(
      KEY_ENTER_COMMAND,
      (payload: KeyboardEvent) => {
        if (
          payload.key === 'Enter'
        ) {
          // Your logic here
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      },
      COMMAND_PRIORITY_CRITICAL
    );
  }, [editor, onEnterKeyPressed]);
```

Returning true would indicate that you have handled the command.

More Info: https://lexical.dev/docs/concepts/commands